# Get-Job Format-Table with Runtimes of Jobs

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I am trying to write a PowerShell 5.1 script for monitoring jobs.
I am having a problem writing a proper Get-Job table, the following is what I have.

```
Get-Job | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property name, state, @{name = 'Runtime'; Expression = {$((get-date)-($_.psbegintime)).ToString('HH:mm')}}
```

What this code returns is a table of named jobs and states, but does populate the runtime column. It works if I remove the `.ToString('HH:mm')` from the code but that populates the runtime column with **Hour:Minute:Second:Millisecond** in this format **HH:mm:ss:fffffff**. How do I remove the Seconds and Milliseconds part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `.ToString(HH:mm)` doesn't work is because the result of:

```
Get-Date - $_.PSBeginTime
```

Is not a [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) object, it's a [`timespan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0) object. Calling `.ToString(HH:mm)` on a `timespan` object throws the following exception:

> MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ToString" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."

According to [TimeSpan.ToString MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-timespan-tostring) formatting is possible however the format is `.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss')`.

Here you have an example of how to achieve what you're looking for:

```
$testJobs = 5

$jobs = 1..$testJobs | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Job {
        'Hello from Job {0}' -f $using:_
        Start-Sleep ([random]::new().Next(5,10))
    }
}
 
while($jobs.State -contains 'Running')
{
    Clear-Host
    Get-Job | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property Name, State, @{
        Name = 'Runtime'
        Expression = {
            ([datetime]::Now - $_.PSBeginTime).ToString('hh\:mm\:ss')
            # .ToString('hh\:mm') for Hours and Minutes only.
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep 1
 }
 
$jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71918903/15339544) shows a similar, *more developed alternative*, using a function to wait for Jobs with progress and a optional **TimeOut** parameter.